# SpringBoot Upload Excel and read as JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

Can you please help me? How to get different data types using map() like String, Integers, Boolean, Double, Date etc. and accepted empty string I used .map(cell::getstringcellvalue). It throws error cannot get a string from a numeric cell because its only accept string and also I want to pass in object because I testing it to dynamic only

Here's my code:

-- Entity.java --

public class Branch {

```
@Column(name = "branch_code", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String branchCode;

@Column(name = "branch_desc", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String branchDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> user;

public Branch(String branchCode, String branchDescription, List<User> user) {
    super();
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
    this.branchDescription = branchDescription;
    this.user = user;
}

public Branch() {
    super();
}

public String getBranchCode() {
    return branchCode;
}

public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
}

public String getBranchDescription() {
    return branchDescription;
}

public void setBranchDescription(String branchDescription) {
    this.branchDescription = branchDescription;
}

public List<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(List<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

--UploadUtils.java--

public class UploadUtils {

```
public Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
    return () -> getStream(rows);
}

public <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}

public Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
    return () -> numberStream(end);
}

public Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
    return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
}
```

}

-- ServiceFile.java --

public List> upload(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

```
    Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("");

    File tempFile = tempDir.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()).toFile();

    file.transferTo(tempFile);

    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = uploadUtils.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

    Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();

    List<String> headerCells = uploadUtils.getStream(headerRow)
            .map(Cell::getStringCellValue) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    int colCount = headerCells.size();

    return rowStreamSupplier.get()
            .skip(1)
            .map(row -> {

                List<String> cellList = uploadUtils.getStream(row)
                        .map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());  

                return uploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
                         .get()
                         .collect(toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

-- Controller.java --

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Map<String, String>> upload(MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
    return employeeService.upload(file);
}
```

Comment: You have to judge the data type first, then use corresponding method provided by Apache POI to retrieve cell value.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is `JSON` then best practice is getting all `Excel` cell contents as formatted strings. This can be achieved using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) from `apache poi`. The method [DataFormatter.formatCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) gets a formatted string from the cell. This string looks the same as `Excel` shows the cell value in it's  `GUI`. If cell content is not text but numeric, date or boolean, then `DataFormatter` formats this content to a string accordingly. If formulas are used in `Excel`, then a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) is needed additional.

So for your code you should using:

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
```

and then

```
.map((cell) -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator))
```

instead of

```
.map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
```

in the cell stream of the rows.

Complete working example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ReadExcelUsingStreams {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  File file = new File("Excel.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = UploadUtils.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

  Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();
  List<String> headerCells = UploadUtils.getStream(headerRow)
   .map(Cell::getStringCellValue) 
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

  int colCount = headerCells.size();

  List<Map<String, String>> content = rowStreamSupplier.get()
   .skip(1)
   .map(row -> 
    {
     List<String> cellList = UploadUtils.getStream(row)
      .map((cell) -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());  
     return UploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
      .get()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
    })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println(content);

  workbook.close();
 }
}

class UploadUtils {

 static Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
    return () -> getStream(rows);
 }

 static <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
 }

 static Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
    return () -> numberStream(end);
 }

 static Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
    return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
 }
}
```

Since you have mentioned empty cells, please note: As told in [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) the `Iterator` will only return the cells defined in the file. This are largely those with values or styling. Really empty cells are not iterated. So if the `Excel` sheet may contain really empty cells, then this whole approach using `java.util.stream.*` cannot be used since it fully depends on `Iterator`s.

Comment: How to pass it to object to save it to database? sir @axel

Comment: @Bryan Caliwag: What to pass to object? Your code, as well as mine, gets a `List` of `Map`s where values are mapped to headers.

Comment: My next goal is to pass the data to table and save it to database like the Branch table, I dont know how approach to save it Sir @Axel

I have an error that I apply it to branchRepository.save(content);

Comment: @Bryan Caliwag: But this is a new question then. Stackoverflow works as: **One** question - multiple answers to **that** question, so that the **best** answer can be up-voted most. Furthermore: Have you rethought your `java.util.stream.*` approach in terms of possible empty cells in `Excel`? As said, usage of `Iterator`s is not possible then. Your `java.util.stream.*` approach will throw exceptions then.