# Ignore blank Cells but not row Using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating a java program to upload an excel file and read it as Json using spring boot but whenever I am trying to upload my file it shows error and also what can be done to ignore any blank cell but not the row.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1579604789613,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException",
    "message": "Index: 1, Size: 1",
    "path": "/applications/upload"
}
```

the service class is as

```
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file.getInputStream());

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = uploadUtil.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

    Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();

    List<String> headerCells = uploadUtil.getStream(headerRow)
            .map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    int colCount = headerCells.size();

    return rowStreamSupplier.get()
            .skip(1)
            .map(row -> {

                List<String> cellList = uploadUtil.getStream(row)
                        .map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                return uploadUtil.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
                        .get()
                        .collect(toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));

            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Util class

```
    public Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
    return () -> getStream(rows);
}

public <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> rows) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(rows.spliterator(), false);
}

public Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
    return () -> numberStream(end);
}

public Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
    return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 37, Size: 37 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) ~[?:1.8.0_111] 
 at com.application.lms.application.service.UploadService.lambda$upload$2(UploadService.java:57) ~[classes/:?] 
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace

Comment: If your "relevant code" doesn't use Spring classes it's most likely not a Spring related question

Comment: Not all `Excel` cells have string cell value. Do using `DataFormatter` to get a `String` representation of all cell contents. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965976/springboot-upload-excel-and-read-as-json/58970710#58970710 for an example using streams.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i am not able to post the stack trace error but the error is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 37, Size: 37
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at com.application.lms.application.service.UploadService.lambda$upload$2(UploadService.java:57) ~[classes/:?]
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

Comment: @AxelRichter I tried using DataFormatter but no luck it is still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is about a discrepancy between `headerCells.size()` and count of content cells in a row. In concrete case, you have 38 header columns but at least one of your content rows has only 37 content cells. Really empty cells are not iterated by the `Iterable` `row` because they are not present in the XML. This results in a `headerCells.size()` and a `colCount` of 38 (0 to 37) but in a `cellList.size()` of only 37 (0 to 36) . So `cellList::get` fails when `IntStream` is on 37.

So if the Excel sheet may contain really empty cells, then you cannot use the `Iterable` `row`. Instead you need using `Row.getCell` for each column index which has a representation in header row.

Using `Stream`s this could be achieved using a `IntStream` of range 0 to `colCount` same way as you are doing it already to collect the `Map` `headerCells` to `cellList` cell. Then you get the cell from `row::getCell` and the cell value from `formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator)` this returns an empty string for a empty not present cell.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ReadExcelUsingStreams {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream ("Excel.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn);

  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = UploadUtils.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

  Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();
  List<String> headerCells = UploadUtils.getStream(headerRow)
   .map(cell -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

  int colCount = headerCells.size();

  List<Map<String, String>> content = rowStreamSupplier.get()
   .skip(1)
   .map(row -> {
     List<String> cellList = UploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
      .get()
      .map(row::getCell)
      .map(cell -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());  
     return UploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
      .get()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
    })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println(content);

  workbook.close();
 }
}

class UploadUtils {

 static Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
    return () -> getStream(rows);
 }

 static <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
 }

 static Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
    return () -> numberStream(end);
 }

 static Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
    return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
 }
}
```